# Text Dataset for Entity Recognition of personal data

Tags: data-request, geospatial, english, text

I am looking for a data set to train and set up a personal information masking application. Is there a text data set available with the name, location, bank account numbers, SSN, Name, Ip address etc (either anonymized or masked, I am only interested in sentence structure and not the actual SSN or Bank account number)? I am trying to build an application similar to this https://presidio-demo.azurewebsites.net/

Answer (score 0):

[Annotated Corpus for Named Entity Recognition](https://www.kaggle.com/abhinavwalia95/entity-annotated-corpus) - Feature Engineered Corpus annotated with IOB and POS tags

Annotated Corpus for Named Entity Recognition using GMB(Groningen Meaning Bank) corpus for entity classification with enhanced and popular features by Natural Language Processing applied to the data set.

---

[Who starts and who debunks rumors](https://www.kaggle.com/arminehn/rumor-citation) Webpages cited by rumor trackers

---

Best place to explore more datasets

[Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets)

---

[15 Free Datasets and Corpora for Named Entity Recognition (NER)](https://lionbridge.ai/datasets/15-free-datasets-and-corpora-for-named-entity-recognition-ner/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the datasets mentioned in [physician notes with annotated PHI](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/6679/1652). PHI = protected health information, which is basically the personal information you're mentioning.